VB.NET 2019 - Hilo se ejecuta dos veces
Estoy haciendo unas pruebas con este código, pero al ejecutarlo con puntos de interrupción, me di cuenta que se ejecuta dos veces:
tmBackup = Timer a 60.000 milisegundos.
Dim Thread_Backup As Thread

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    tmBackup.Enabled = True 'ACTIVA TIMER
    AddHandler tmBackup.Tick, AddressOf tmBackup_Tick
End Sub

Private Sub tmBackup_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tmBackup.Tick
    Thread_Backup = New Thread(New ThreadStart(AddressOf Ejecuta_Backup))
    Thread_Backup.IsBackground = True
    Thread_Backup.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Ejecuta_Backup() 'SE EJECUTA DOS VECES
   If Now.DayOfWeek = 1 Then 
      If Now.Hour = 7 Then
         ... código
      End If           
   End If      
End Sub


Que es tmBackup ?

@Yussef es un timer, pero si no tiene la cantidad de tiempo, le esta asignando el tiempo por defecto, que no se cual es...

Se ejecuta una vez cada 60 segundos...

ah nooooooooo espera.. agregaste 2 veces el evento al timer... por eso.. si agregas el handles al evento, sobra el addhandler.. o uno o el otro!!!

Toda la razón, eliminé la línea:  AddHandler tmBackup.Tick, AddressOf tmBackup_Tick y funcionó correctamente.

Eliminando la línea, funcionó correctamente:
AddHandler tmBackup.Tick, AddressOf tmBackup_Tick


Esto.. no es una repuesta per se.. la respuesta debe explicar el problema y como solucionarlo... mira [answer]
